# Azure SQL Managed Instance: RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3201)

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-managed-database

I'm trying to restore my database into Azure SQL Managed instance from blob storage URL. But I'm getting below error.

RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3201)

I tried to restore it to localhost and that worked fine.
Blob storage is having all the permissions.

Why is it working in localhost and not in Azure SQL managed instance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot open backup device '******' operating system error 5 (Access is denied)

This can because of it not able to access the storage account.

To access data from outside of the virtual network in Managed instance public endpoint for a managed instance helps you to achieve that. **By default, it is Disabled turn it to `Enable`.**

[image]

And also confirm that you **enable public network access in storage account from all networks.**

[image]

Also see,

**For more information refer,**

[Backup and restore SQL Server to Azure Blob storage](https://sqlserverguides.com/backup-and-restore-sql-server-to-azure-blob-storage/)

[Troubleshooting potential backup/restore issues on Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/troubleshooting-potential-backup-restore-issues-on-azure-sql/ba-p/633556?lightbox-message-images-633556=116415i12D12C318CD65A32)